# Getting 4-band raster from gdal_calc.py

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I have 4 channel rasters in GeoTIFF.

[image]
[image]

I need to find the average value of these rasters and present them in the form of another raster, also in RGB, and I get a black and white file.

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

```
 gdal_calc.py -A /var/www/html/algorithm/cut103.tif -B /var/www/html/algorithm/cut1031.tif  --outfile=result.tif --calc="(A+B)/2"[![Вот что получается.][1]][1]
```

I also tried to use `gdal_translate -of VRT input.tif input.vrt`

My input.vrt:

```
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
    <Entry c1="170" c2="170" c3="255"/>
    <Entry c1="85" c2="170" c3="255"/>
    <Entry c1="66" c2="33" c3="18"/>
    <Entry c1="159" c2="81" c3="42"/>
    <Entry c1="205" c2="169" c3="21"/>
    <Entry c1="253" c2="254" c3="3"/>
    <Entry c1="230" c2="236" c3="6"/>
    <Entry c1="208" c2="223" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="185" c2="207" c3="2"/>
    <Entry c1="162" c2="192" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="138" c2="175" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="114" c2="160" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="91" c2="142" c3="3"/>
    <Entry c1="69" c2="129" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="45" c2="112" c3="0"/>
    <Entry c1="37" c2="96" c3="45"/>
    <Entry c1="21" c2="84" c3="45"/>
    <Entry c1="21" c2="68" c3="45"/>
```

Plese? someone, help

Comment: Konstantin, this site allows communication only in English. I suggest using a google translator and editing the question. Константин, на данном сайте разрешено общение только на английском языке. Предлагаю воспользоваться переводчиком и отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: @ComradeChe, translate done.

Comment: What software is used to display the resulting image? Are the pixel values really zero (black), 255 (white), or is this an image display (render) issue?

Comment: @ComradeChe, i use QGis, pixels valuses realy zero, i dont created an alpha channel.

Comment: @ComradeChe, 
i have added images as examples

Comment: You take 2 rasters (A and B) and perform the math operation `(A + B) / 2`, the result is a raster image with one band. I don't understand - what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @ComradeChe, i am trying to achieve a color raster in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify band for each file before calculations (see `--A_band` parameter in [gdal_calc](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html)) then use [gdal_merge](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html) to merge 3 gdal_calc outputs into RGB raster.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.

Comment: When working with two rasters, everything turns out fine, but with an increase in the number of processed rasters, it again produces a black and white result